# Internal redirect error with htaccess with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

Every 1-2 days I get an internal server error due to too many internal redirects. It just happened again and I don't know what to do, these are the logs I see (I activated tracing on mod rewrite):

[image]

This is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%.       {HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /it/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]      
</IfModule>`
```

Is there something off? I can I prevent the internal redirect to keep happening? It seems related to the index.php and the overall rule for /it/

I have WP-rocket active, but it happens with it or without it active.

I tried almost everything, updating all my services (Nginx and Apache), deactivating plugins, etc.

Comment: The rule that prevents further rewriting when the internal URL already points to the index.php, probably needs to take the `it/` path prefix into account? `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` -> `RewriteRule ^it/index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: do you mean like this:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%.       {HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /it/
RewriteRule ^it/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]      
</IfModule>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Is that working, or are you getting errors right away?

Comment: It's actually working now but I don't know it I will get the error again...as I said it happens every 24-48 hours and apparently without any reason

Comment: It might be helpful but in the logs I keep seeing every seconds errors like this one: [rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(493): 116.202.196.169 - - [cherieswood.com/sid#5567d7539058][rid#7fb9dc018f28/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/cherieswood.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.php'

and it happens for several URLs and cases, not sure what that is

Comment: Does that get listed as an actual _error_? It's basically just saying that the pattern `.` gets tested against the current internal URL, `index.php`.

Comment: Yes it categorizes all of them as Apache Errors, but that's Plesk, so it might be something due to that.

Comment: look at this: https://ibb.co/26xNWvV - all of them are like that

Comment: Those are all just rewrite logging outputs. If your system is configured to write those to the error log, instead of to a separate file, that might explain why Plesk lists them as "Apache errors." They are just informational in nature though, none of what that screenshot show is an actual error.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help, I will keep monitoring this for a few days to see if it happens again or you solved it

Comment: Still getting this today. Any idea of what else I could check?

Comment: Still getting an internal server error due to too many redirects, or only still getting these log info messages?

Comment: Just a general 500 error right now and not much in the logs if not the same things